# How to solve this query

Tags: sql

i have to two tables in sql:
tbl_Rooms(Room_Id, Room_Beds);
tbl_AllocatedRooms(Room_Id, Bed_No);

i want to get the result as:
1: List of all the rooms in which no bed is allocated.
2: List of rooms in which one or more beds are allocated also the number of remaining beds(for example if i have a room_id = 2 in tbl_Rooms with Beds = 5 and 2 of these beds are allocated i want to get the remaining number of beds)

i have done the first one but cant figure how to get the second one.
Here is my query for the first one:

```
 SELECT * INTO #tempUnAllocated FROM tbl_Rooms WHERE Room_Id NOT IN 
(SELECT Room_Id FROM tbl_Allocation);
```

Comment: For your second query, you don't want any rooms where no bed has been allocated?    Only rooms with at least one bed allocated?   Do you want to include rooms where all the beds are allocated?

Comment: yes, only those rooms in which one or more(any number) of beds are allocated, and also want to get the count of remaining beds in that room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.room_id,A.room_beds,count(B.bed_no) as allocated_beds,
(A.room_beds - count(B.bed_no)) as remaining_beds
from tbl_rooms A LEFT JOIN tbl_AllocatedRooms B
ON A.room_id = B.room_id
group by A.room_id,A.room_beds
having allocated_beds < room_beds
```

You can refer the solution [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef058/11).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, although a solution using a CTE might be more readable, if your RDBMS supports them.

```
SELECT a.Room_Id, (SELECT Room_Beds FROM tbl_Rooms r WHERE r.Room_Id=a.Room_Id)-COUNT(*) AS unallocatedBeds
FROM tbl_allocatedRooms a
GROUP BY a.Room_Id
```